# Android - Let the activity remain in its original Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

When I open an Activity I want that activity to remain in that orientation that was opened.
For example, if I open it in PORTRAIT mode, then the user wont' be able to change it to landscape, and when I open it in LANDSCAPE, then the user won't be able to change to portrait.  (I need this for a video player)

To achieve this I get the current screen orientation, and then set it, like this:

```
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
```

If I open the Activity in PORTRAIT mode, and try to switch to LANDSCAPE by rotating the phone, it doesn't - this is as expected. The issue is that if the activity is opened in LANDSCAPE  and I attempt to rotate to portrait - it does.

I don't understand why this might happen.

The code appears in the onCreate(), above the setContentView()

Comment: did you save your orientation on configuration changes? save the int and then restore it before setting the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` and `setRequestedOrientation(orientation);` work with different constants. You could try reading the documentation for both of them, and doing the mapping between them.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

    }
```